# DB Update doesn't work

Tags: php, pdo

Hi im using `PDO` to update some fields of a MySQL database. I've written a class called "bakeIT" which connects to a DB and updates some fields depending on the parameters of the method `simple_update()`.

Somehow the first instantiation call to `BakeIT()->simple_update()` is working but not the second one? Why is that? I'm getting really crazy on that...

Edit:
I found out some errors:

> string(85) "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" Fatal error: Call to a member
>   function prepare() on a non-object in
>   BakeIT.php

The table looks like the following:[image]

```
class BakeIT {

    function simple_update(
    $tablename,
    $fieldname,
    $value,
    $id,
    $idname,
    $token,
    $tokenvalue){

        $conn=$this->connect_db();
        $sql= "UPDATE $tablename SET $fieldname=? WHERE $idname=? AND $token=?";
        $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($value,$id,$tokenvalue));
        $conn = null;}
}


//This as the first query works!        
$saveanchor = new BakeIT();
$saveanchor->simple_update('navigation','anchor','whoo',5,'idnavigation','hash','3234'); 

//This as the second query not!    
$savetitle = new BakeIT();
$savetitle->simple_update('navigation','linkname','kawoom',5,'idnavigation','hash','3234');
```

Comment: Don't you think that your SQL statement is dangerous? You complicate a blind sql inection much, but I think it would be possible. Btt does the field linkname exists?

Comment: Not working..you mean some exact error or it silently do nothing?

Comment: @rekire, rkosegi thanks for your help. Linkname does exist...if i swap $saveanchor with $savetitle everything works fine...Fails means it silently does nothing...

Comment: are you sure the first one working? have you tried to edit the db record? is there a `linkname` field in the table? and why don't you check the return value of the execute call?

Comment: @rekire how would you prevent sql injection? I thought this prepared statements are secure ;-?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thank you for your help! How would you check the return value the best way? You mean Exception/Error handling with try and catch (Exception $e) ?

Comment: I answered your question and added an example about the secutity risk. @Jurudocs I would write serveral prepered statements where the fields are static.

Comment: @jurudocs: They're secure if you use ONLY placeholders. you're directly injecting `$fieldname` and `$idname`, which utterly negates the point of using placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `linkname` doesn't exists.

To my comment about the security: So far I know the prepred statemend prevents an attacker to inject any bad values into the field content.

```
function example($value, $primarykey, $condition) {
    $q = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET somefield=? WHERE $primarykey=?");
    $q->execute(array($value,$condition));
}
```

It is not possible to manipulate the parameters `$value` and `$condition` but you can set `$tableid` to `1=1 --` which would override your compleate table.

E.g. `example(12, 34, "1=1 --");`that would execute this here:

```
UPDATE table SET somefield=12 WHERE 1=1 --=34
```

Comment: thanks for your help again...im sure that there are no probs with the table columns...see the above edit about the errors...

Comment: @Jurudocs I think the database connection is closed after the first update. It seems that `$this->connect_db()` returns on the second call `null`.

Comment: @Jurudocs If you prevent that `null` is retuned and you return a valid db handle everythink should work.

Comment: pooh thank sounds like advanced stuff how can i keep the connection open...but...iven if it closes the connection it could create another is it?

Comment: @Jurudocs that isn't such complicated just don't call a close function. Normally that should be enough to use the handle a second time. If the connection is closed you can normally open it a second time but that is not very good for the performance to close and reopen the db connection.

Comment: i got it! Its how i load the external accessdata for accessing my db. Require_once doesn't work...it has to be just require...Anyway thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

okay i got it! It's the require_once for the external db-access data. with only "require" the data.php (script with db-access variables) everything works fine...

Thanks for helping though!